# LDAP Event Filter For Null Element

Tags: java, ldap, osgi

I have a list of things in my event properties where elements could be null. I want to create a LDAP string to match the null elements.

Consider this working example:

```
private final BundleContext context = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(LdapTest.class).getBundleContext();
private final EventAdmin eventAdmin = this.context.getService(this.context.getServiceReference(EventAdmin.class));

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    final String value = "test";

    // register a listener

    final Dictionary<String, Object> serviceProperties = new Hashtable<>();
    serviceProperties.put(EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, new String[] { "myTopic" });
    serviceProperties.put(EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER, "(myProperty=" + value + ")");

    final boolean[] called = { false };
    final ServiceRegistration<EventHandler> listener = this.context.
            registerService(EventHandler.class, e -> called[0] = true, serviceProperties);

    // fire event

    Assert.assertFalse(called[0]);
    final Map<String, Object> eventProperties = new HashMap<>();
    eventProperties.put("myProperty", Arrays.asList(value));

    this.eventAdmin.sendEvent(new Event("myTopic", eventProperties));
    Assert.assertTrue(called[0]);

    listener.unregister();
}
```

Now if I set `value = null`, what does the `EVENT_FILTER` have to look like to make the test work again?

I tried "`(!myProperty=*)`" and "`(!(myProperty=*))`", but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar problem, that's how I fixed it for now.

I added a second property to hold the information of if a `null` value is present:

```
 List<String> values = //...
 eventProperties.put("myProperty", values);
 eventProperties.put("myProperty.hasNull", values.contains(null));
```

So I can query using this new property:

```
serviceProperties.put(EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER, 
        value == null ? "(myProperty.hasNull=true)" : "(myProperty=" + value + ")");
```

It's not perfect, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP filter expression `(myProperty=*)` will evaluate to true if the property is set, false otherwise. There is no way in the LDAP filter expression to test for a null value. I would suggest not setting the event property if it has a null value.

Comment: I isn't a null property, it's a null element inside a list. And I can filter for any other element inside the list, so it's weird I can't filter for that one.

Comment: The LDAP filter expression language has no way to express a null value so that you can test for it. "null" is just an ordinary string and not a special value meaning the null value.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some success using filters similar to:

```
(myProperty=\00)
```

The “\00” is the escaped sequence for null.
Some of this depends on if the "null" is the only thing in the value.
We have encountered scenarios where values coming from SQL datastores will end up with null values and have been able to use that filter.

If the "null" is within the attribute value  (like Tom<"null">Smith), I know of no other method than to read the attribute values as binary and parse the characters looking for "nulls".

-jim

Comment: Using `(myProperty=\00)` doesn't work in the test class above and not in my actual use case, no matter if there are other values present besides the `null`value.